# Accessing properties of an object in an array

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an array of objects and I can print them out, so I know they are present.

The problem I have is that I cannot access the variables of the objects.

e.g.

```
// This prints out correctly
NSLog(@"asset frame in select mode is at index:%d is %@", i, [[AssetsSingleton sharedMySingleton].assetFrames objectAtIndex:i]);
```

This print outs

> asset frame in select mode is at index:0 is
>   Asset: 0x8087040; frame = (4 2; 75 75); layer = CALayer: 0x808bd00>>

I have the member variables for an Asset as follows

```
UIImageView *overlayView;
BOOL selected;
id parent;
```

The problem is I cannot access these e.g. overlayView using

```
[[AssetsSingleton sharedMySingleton].assetFrames objectAtIndex:i].overlayView.hidden = TRUE;
```

How can I access these members? The print out seems to be showing that the array holds an Asset.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either cast or assign the object to a variable before using its properties:

```
Foo *foo = [myArray objectAtIndex:12345];
foo.bar = 67890;
```

Or:

```
((Foo *)[myArray objectAtIndex:12345]).bar = 67890;
```

Properties are only available to you when the compiler knows the type of the object.

Answer (score 1):

You say you "cannot access these" -- what is the problem? Is it a compiler error? What error?

Assuming your error is what I think it is:

NSArray (and similar classes such as NSDictionary) hold objects - NSObject. You must therefore cast them to their actual types before accessing them as that type.

Try the following:

```
Asset *asset = (Asset*)[[AssetsSingleton sharedMySingleton].assetFrames objectAtIndex:i];
asset.overlayView.hidden = TRUE;
```

Comment: Thanks. yeah. I was thinking in java for some reason. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to cast the array item to an Asset first?

```
((Asset*)[[AssetsSingleton sharedMySingleton].assetFrames objectAtIndex:i]).overlayView.hidden = TRUE;
```